# Sharing audio(Mic) input to multiple apps in Android

Tags: android, audio, oboe

As per official [documentation](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/media/sharing-audio-input)

> Android 10 (API level 29) and higher imposes a priority scheme that can switch the input audio stream between apps while they are running. In most cases, if a new app acquires the audio input, the previously capturing app continues to run but receives silence. In some cases, the system can continue to deliver audio to both apps. The various sharing scenarios are explained below.

Other than some [special cases](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/media/sharing-audio-input#sharing_scenarios), audio is not shared between apps.

But I have seen many apps sharing the audio input without being in the above special cases.
For eg. [Zoom](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=us.zoom.videomeetings&hl=en_IN), when I'm on a call in zoom and start an audio recorder then both the apps are getting audio though zoom audio decreases in intensity.

Similarly, [Omlet arcade](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=mobisocial.arcade&hl=en_IN) is able to record mic audio even when mic access is given to other apps.

How is it possible? And as per the documentation, this shouldn't be allowed.

**Update:**
Was able to achieve it with the usage of [Oboe](https://github.com/google/oboe). But it is not consistent on all devices. This also causes a sync issue in my live streaming app. Audio is audible with a delay

Answer (score 0):

This is not possible in Android 5+ . You need a rooted phone to perform this action. In Omlet Arcade Whenever you play a Game and switch ON in-game mic, Omlet Arcade will stop receiving any audio input. However, Omlet Arcade will still function but you have to restart it in order to get voice input back.
Though, in a recent MIUI bug, People were able to listen to calls on Zoom and in-game mic apps. In your case, it might be not official Android and Edited Android like MIUI and OxygenOS

Comment: But Omlet seems to be working on Pixel device, so maybe it is an Android bug or there is a special configuration to achieve it.

Comment: What I just told you is absolutely same. Pixel uses Chrome OS with Primary Android which may achieve what you told. I have actually rooted my MIUI 11 manually by booting into bootloader and Android 6+ is very hard to crack through apps like Kingroot

Comment: Pity the user left... Still though, for anyone that might know, "You need a rooted phone to perform this action." - like I do have. What should I do now? I also have the app as system app. If [this](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/media/sharing-audio-input#pre-behavior) is the way, I don't know how to get it to work...